# Is there a website / service with publicly accessible database of workouts?

Tags: workout, websites

I am looking for a website / service that has database of different popular strength-related workouts. 
Ideally it would be something with API, but a website with exhaustive list of easily accessible programs will work too.

I found http://wger.de but I unfortunately there is no public access to workouts.

I also found this: 
http://www.powerliftingtowin.com/powerlifting-programs/

But it is a bit too powerlifting-specific.

Comment: Possibly something in here: http://www.wlinfo.com/resource.htm and http://www.bodybuilding.com/fun/workoutdatabase.htm (Neither has an API that I can see, however.)

Answer (score 2):

[Exrx.net](http://www.exrx.net/) has been my go-to for years. It might not be perfect, but I think it has the highest blend of objectivity, science-based approach, breadth, and physiology. No API however.

Answer (score 1):

I've had good luck with weighttraining.com for descriptions and videos. I also know myfitnesspal.com has an API for their food/nutrition/exercise database.

There's also Fat Secret http://platform.fatsecret.com/api/ and Open Fitness http://www.openfitapi.com/about for API tools, but I'm not sure exactly what you're trying to do so I don't know if those are helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Your in luck- a huge one is bodybuilding.com. Don't be too intimidated the demonstrators are nice too look at and one piece of muscle but it is very professional. Nowadays theres a million more as its trendy. Do a search for exercise / strength train / workout video.